# How can i make it so my runningtotal rows is in a percentage format where 100.00000 would equal 100% and so forth

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
select gla.account_number, gla.account_description,   
line_item_description as expense, ili.line_item_amount as cost,
```

So the line under is where i am having trouble, how do i make it so that when **I divide line_item_amount by the sum of line_item_amount / 100 that it will output into a percentage format.**

```
sum(line_item_amount) over (order by line_item_amount desc) as RunningTotal,
line_item_amount / sum(line_item_amount / 100) over (order by 
line_item_amount desc) as percent

from
invoice_line_items ili
join general_ledger_accounts gla
on ili.account_number = gla.account_number

where account_description not like 'freight' and account_description not 
like 'telephone'

order by cost desc
```

Here's what it should look like:
[image]

This is what mine looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multiplying by `100.0`, and also perhaps use `ROUND`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(line_item_amount) OVER (ORDER BY line_item_amount DESC) AS RunningTotal,
    ROUND(100.0 * line_item_amount /
        SUM(line_item_amount) OVER (ORDER BY line_item_amount DESC), 2) AS percent
FROM invoice_line_items ili
INNER JOIN general_ledger_accounts gla
    ON ili.account_number = gla.account_number
WHERE
    account_description <> 'freight' AND account_description <> 'telephone'
ORDER BY
   cost DESC;
```

Notes:

I replaced your `LIKE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause with regular inequalities, because you were not using `%` wildcards.  The version above is the same logic as what you had, though perhaps you intended to use something along the lines of `WHERE account_description NOT LIKE '%freight%'`.  If so, then edit my code as you want.

Comment: Yes you were right using <> is more efficient. However, i copied and pasted the ROUND to percent line and i was left with this. and the results were 0.01, 0.00, and so forth.

Comment: I made a mistake.  You should be _multiplying_ by 100 to get the percentage, not dividing.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you, I appreciated the help.